# A function that takes an object as parameter and erase the object param

Tags: python

Is it possible to build a function that takes an object as parameter, then return the object without the object's parameters?

The issue that I'm having is: those params are not fixed, they can be anything and I need to get rid of them (remove all parameters from the object)

Any thoughts?

Comment: Please clarify what it is that you wish to do.  What do you mean by remove all parameters from the object?  Do you mean the properties?  Attributes?  Methods?

Comment: What's the context - can you show how you would _use_ such a thing? An object without any parameters (attributes?) seems a bit pointless.

Comment: @ewokx I'm building health metrics for some agents. Those metrics objects can contain different attributes depending on agents. At this level everything is fine.
The issue is that when I try to make a test, I'm passing those metrics as injection and I would like to get rid of what is stick on it as attribute.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have added a comment, can you please check it?

Comment: Please give a [mre]. Why do you need to remove the added attributes, rather than e.g. creating a new object to inject in each test?

Comment: Are you asking how you can remove attributes from an instance of some class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally think that your question displays some bad practices in code architecture you chose to implement. So I strongly recommend to rethink it.

However, this is possible in general (you didn't provide reproducible example so I imagine it on my own):

```
def remove_attributes(obj):
    # Get a list of all attributes (including methods) of the object
    attributes = dir(obj)

    # Exclude special (magic and private) attributes and methods
    attributes_to_keep = [attr for attr in attributes if not attr.startswith('__')]

    # Remove all attributes except the special ones
    for attr in attributes_to_keep:
        delattr(obj, attr)


# Example
class SampleObject:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.secret = "This should be removed"


obj = SampleObject("Alice", 30)
print("Before removal:", obj.__dict__)
remove_attributes(obj)
print("After removal:", obj.__dict__)
```

```
>>> python3 main.py
Before removal: {'name': 'Alice', 'age': 30, 'secret': 'This should be removed'}
After removal: {}
```

**Edit**.
If you want to delete specific attrs, I missed it first:

```
def remove_attributes(obj, attrs_to_delete: list):
    for attr in attrs_to_delete:
        delattr(obj, attr)


# Example
class SampleObject:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.secret = "This should be left"


obj = SampleObject("Alice", 30)
print("Before removal:", obj.__dict__)
remove_attributes(obj, ['name', 'age'])
print("After removal:", obj.__dict__)
```